# How to connect MongoDB to power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

everyone! need to connect powerBI to mongoDB
what I have:
I installed mongodb bi connector and ODBC driver.
started mongod

[mongod start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxjEI.png)

and mongosqld

[mongosqld start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azjb5.png)

also did: mongoimport --db localtest --collection zips --file C:\data\db\zips.json
After that, with following dsn connected pbi to this file:

[local dsn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps4ET.png)

So, now I need to connect not ot local file, I thought it would be enough to create a new dsn with new credentials - but it was not(

[connection that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4AER.png)

Please, help me, what else should I do?

Comment: What are those images? Can't you copy'n'paste the text they contain? That way, they are easier to find if anyone else has the same error messages, for example. That said, this doesn't seem to be about programming, so it's off-topic here. As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? If not please give us more information. From the last screenshot, I can only see that perhaps the port should be set to 3307. It depends which one did you set up in mongosqld.conf... Default port is 3307 [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/launch/)